# TeXShop not invoking biber with XeLaTeX

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber, mactex, texshop

I installed current MacTeX version (`20150613`) and then updated TeXShop to most recent version, `Version 3.61`.

In the BibTeX engine setting, I wrote `biber`, and in the document I additionally have:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
%!BIB TS-program = biber

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
```

I'm typesetting with XeLaTeX through `Typeset ⌘T` command multiple times and references are not resolved. It seems that `biber` is not invoked. If I go to terminal and manually invoke `biber document.bcf`, my references get resolved in the next typesetting pass.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have a look at [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864), please.

Comment: I think that I already did all actions described in TexShop section of that question. Have I missed something?

Comment: Mhhh, the only difference I can see is that the answer also suggests `% !BIB program = biber` which you are missing, but I'm not sure if that changes anything.

Comment: Otherwise it would be nice if you could check if biber is actually called and then aborts with an (unreported) error, or if something else is going on. Another thing I could imagine is that pressing "Typesetting" does not actually run the bibliography program, maybe you need to press another button for that (maybe one marked "bibliography").

Comment: Console log of TeXShop doesn't show `biber` being invoked at all. Bibliography-related message is `No file document.bbl` and this continues with warnings about undefined citations.

Comment: As I said, maybe you have to invoke Biber manually, is there another button besides "typeset" that you could press? (There is a drop-down menu next to "typeset" I gather from the screenshots I have seen, maybe you can find something there).

Comment: You were right. I needed to manually select BibTeX in the dropdown next to `Typeset` which then invokes `biber`. Can you add it as an answer so I can give you credit?

Comment: I think then your question is more or less a duplicate of [BibTeX doesn't produce any .bbl files on Mac OS](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/133716/35864). You might be interested in Adam Liter's comment under the accepted answer.

Comment: Agreed. I'll set it as duplicate and vote for close.