# How do I run Biber on TeXShop?

Tags: biblatex, biber, texshop

I am trying to include the bibliography in a file I'm writing. The editor I'm using is TeXShop (OS is mac OSX).

I'm following a tutorial where I found that to include the bibliography using Biber I need a `.bib` file and the following commands:

```
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes} 
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib_file.bib}
```

and then

```
\printbibliography
```

Then it says that, in order to make the bibliography appear in the document, I should:

- Compile
- Run Biber from the editor
- Re-compile twice

But how do I run Biber from TeXShop?

PS I've already set Biber as my default BibTeX Engine in Preferences/Engine, but I don't know how to run it. If I simply compile the document (i.e. press "Typeset") no bibliography will appear.

Comment: Funny you should ask, we seem to have just the answer for you [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864)

Comment: @moewe I've already set Biber as my default BibTeX Engine in Preferences/Engine, but I don't know how to run it. If I simply compile the document (i.e. press "Typeset") no bibliography will appear.

Comment: Aha! Now we're talking. Unfortunately I don't have a Mac, so I can only go by the screenshots I've seen on the web, but is there are drop down menu next to the "typeset" button where you can choose something like "bibliograhy"/"BibTeX"/"Biber"?

Comment: Hotkey: typeset/bibtex = Shift-Cmd-B

Comment: [BibTeX doesn't produce any .bbl files on Mac OS](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/133716/35864) seems to suggest you have to choose "BibTeX" in the drop-down menu or use some kind of hotkey: `SHIFT`+`CMD`+`B`.

Comment: You can use a little helper like `latexmk` or `arara` to run all the necessary commands for you with one click: [all-in-one-engine for TeXShop](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41271/35864) & [How to use arara with TeXShop](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/175671/35864)

Comment: @moewe If you want you can turn the comment in an answrer so that I can accept it and everybody with my same problem will be able to read what the solution is :)

Comment: @valerio92 I've updated the linked answer to make it clear how to run `biber` as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you have the .bib file place the line

% !TEX TS–program = pdflatexmk

at the top of your .tex file. Then typeset using Typeset->Typeset (Cmd-T).  That will automatically run biber when necessary and all the necessary runs of pdflatex.

If you want to create a .bib file try using BibDesk which you can find in /Applications/TeX.

If you always will use biber you can also make it the default bibtex engine in TeXShop->Preferences->Engine.

Comment: It works. But could I ask what does this command do exactly?

Comment: That `command', called a directive, tells TeXShop to use one of the special processing engines. The pdflatexmk engine uses the latexmk pearl program to use pdflatex then bibtex or biber (automatically) and make index, if necessary, finishing off with the proper number of runs of pdflatex to resolve all cross references. See Help->TeXShop Tips and Tricks for more information.

Comment: @HerbSchulz Is there a difference between `pdflatex` and `pdflatexmk` when called for TexShop?

Comment: @Jim : `pdflatex` simply runs pdflatex once while `pdflatexmk` uses the `latexmk` perl script to automatically completely typeset your document resolving all cross-references, citations and indexes.

Comment: NOTE: If you don't want to use the pdflatexmk engine and you don't want to change the default to always use biber as noted in the anser above you can use biber on a document by document basis by using the TeXShop directive `$ !BIB program = biber` near the top of the Source file. Then using Typeset->BibTeX (Shft-Cmd-B) will us biber instead of bibtex for that document.